# Subsonic not working in Shared Hosting Environment

Tags: subsonic

I Tried GODaddy and BizHost.Net, neither works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think SubSonic needs full trust which GoDaddy doesn't offer....  Don't know about BizHost.

I did find this though on how to get SubSonic working in medium trust:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/94319/SubSonic - read page 7 Trust level

I use DiscountASP.Net and they do allow full trust

Comment: BizHost does allow full trust.  Any idea why it would be different then DiscountAsp.Net?  I should mention I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any details, I could just guess.

SubSonic queries the information_schema in order to generate the DAL.
In most hosting environments you only have limited access (if any) to the information_schema for security reason.

You could generate the DAL locally and copy the files to the server.